# VBA Access declare variables names using loop

Tags: loops, ms-access, variables, vba

How do I declare variable names in a loop?  For example I need to declare Combo1Count, Combo2Count, Combo3Count, and so on :

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 6
    Dim Combo & i & Count as Integer
Next i
```

Then later on I will need to refer to these variables eg:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    If Combo & i & Count > 0 ....
Next i
```

Comment: Is there is a reason you do not use an array? You can Dim as Variant and then ReDim when you know how many position/indexes you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is not the issue in VBA. The issue is ... that you can't.

A work-around is using Select Case:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 6
    Select Case 1
        Dim Combo1 As Integer
    Select Case 2
        Dim Combo2 As Integer
    ' ....
    Select Case 6
        Dim Combo6 As Integer
    End Select
Next i
```

which, of course, doesn't make sense. So use:

```
Dim Combo1 As Integer
Dim Combo2 As Integer
' ....
Dim Combo6 As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array to store your count values.

```
dim myArray(1 to 6) as Variant
dim i as Integer

myArray(1) = combo1Count
myArray(2) = combo2Count
...

'to acces the Values simply use
for i = 1 to 6
    if myArray(i) > 0 then ...
next i
```

Answer (score -1):

Variables defined within a loop are subject to "Scope" rules of each language. For VBA, you can read more here: [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications - Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693)

As a result, any variable defined within a loop, or conditional statements (etc) will not be accessible outside of that scope. If you want a variable to receive a value within a loop, then you should Dim it above the loop declaration. It can then be accessed later in your code as needed (even within loops)

Comment: The link goes to VB.NET documentation not VBA.